# Redirect all Skype Messages from one profile to another

Tags: redirect, chat, message, profile, skype

As the title says, is there a way to redirect all skype messages I receive
from one profile to another ? The Skype support states that you can activate
SMS messages which will get redirected but I just want simple chat messages
to be redirected from one profile to another automatically.
Just to clarify, both profiles will be online and not one offline and the other
online.

All code/forums/books will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Skype doesn't support incoming text messages - you can set up an SMS ID which allows you to send SMS messages from Skype and receive the answer to your mobile phone.

To do this, go to Skype -> Preferences -> Messaging. After you have validated your mobile number, all SMS messages you send from Skype will display your mobile number as the sender ID.

Comment: If this gets confirmed Ill mark your answer as correct. But I really wish there
was a way to redirect Normal Chat Messages.

Comment: Sure, give it a try and see if it helps. you can also contact Skype customer service directly if you wish. :)

Comment: Even big M says it`s impossible https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/skype-question-can-i-forward-messages-to-another/16d084c6-15c0-4512-8f42-d653b95bb60a

Answer (score 0):

There is commercial tool for this. It works across many messengers but the monthly cost is quite big: https://sameroom.io

Also here is the most relevant discussion of the stuff: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4046